# Return row with unique values across columns of same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, distinct, lateral-join

I have the data like this:

| CODE | EMAIL0 | EMAIL1 | EMAIL2 | EMAIL3 | EMAIL4 | EMAIL5 | EMAIL6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | abc@gmail.com | q@gmail.com | q@gmail.com | f@gmail.com | h@gmail.com | u@gmail.com | y@gmail.com |
| DEF | def@gmail.com | k@gmail.com | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | g@gmail.com |
| XYZ | xyz@gmail.com | i@gmail.com | i@gmail.com | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |

I need the query to return only the second row with `CODE=DEF`, because `EMAIL1` to `EMAIL6` are all unique values.

Basically I need the rows with unique values for `EMAIL1` to `EMAIL6`.
Here `CODE` will always be unique.

I tried with `CROSS JOIN` but it did not work out.

Comment: You really should be fixing your design, having 6 email columns is breaking one of the basic precipcals of 3NF.

Answer (score 0):

If you want rows where no email is repeated, you can unpivot the emails to rows in a lateral join, and then compare the count of distinct non-`null` values to the count of non-`null` values:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
cross apply (
    select count(distinct email) cnt1, count(email) cnt2
    from (values (email0), (email1), ...) as x(email)
) x
where x.cnt1 = x.cnt2
```

Comment: I am not able to get the query syntax correct. I replaced the mytable of above query with my actual table name,but am not able to write the full query.

Comment: @jayeshkshirsagar: which query are you running, and which error are you getting exactly?

Comment: I have written the following query:

Comment: I have written the following query:  Suppose I take on Email 1 and Email2 for now..In the final query I need to compare Email1 to Email6..There should be no duplicate in 1 to 6

  

select t.*
from QUALIFIED_UNIQUE_EMAIL_R t
cross apply (
    select count(distinct email_1) cnt1, count(email_2) cnt2
    from (values (email_1), (email_2)) as x(email)
) x
where x.cnt1 = x.cnt2

Error : Msg 4101, Level 15, State 1, Line 252
Aggregates on the right side of an APPLY cannot reference columns from the left side.

Comment: @jayeshkshirsagar: `select count(distinct email_1) cnt1, count(email_2) cnt2` should be `select count(distinct email) cnt1, count(email) cnt2`, as in my query.